# remove an element from an XML

Tags: c#, xml

I want to remove an element from an XML Tree and I tried using the method mentioned in the following URL to do that.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387051.aspx

My XML is kinda different from the above and when I tried to use this it only removes the Grandchild1 in the first node. It doesn't do it for the second one.

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(@"<Root>
    <Child1>
        <GrandChild1/>
        <GrandChild2/>
        <GrandChild3/>
    </Child1>
    <Child1>
        <GrandChild1/>
        <GrandChild2/>
        <GrandChild3/>
    </Child1>
</Root>");

root.Element("Child1").Element("GrandChild1").Remove();
```

output after executing:

```
<Child1>       
    <GrandChild2/>
    <GrandChild3/>
</Child1>
<Child1>
    <GrandChild1/>
    <GrandChild2/>
    <GrandChild3/>
</Child1>
```

expected output:

```
    <Child1>
        <GrandChild2/>
        <GrandChild3/>
    </Child1>
    <Child1>
        <GrandChild2/>
        <GrandChild3/>
    </Child1>
```

Why doesn't it do it and how can I make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Element` method only returns a *single* element. You want:

```
root.Elements("Child1").Elements("GrandChild1").Remove();
```

That uses:

- The normal [`XContainer.Elements`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975) method
- The [`Extensions.Elements`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351784(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method (on `IEnumerable<T> where T : XContainer`)
- The [`Extensions.Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method (on `IEnumerable<T> where T : XNode`)

So that will find every `GrandChild1` element directly under a `Child1` element directly under the root. If you actually don't care *where* the `GrandChild1` element is found, you an use

```
root.Descendants("GrandChild1").Remove();
```

... but using `Elements` gives you a bit more control.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `Element` method, it just returns an element. You can use the [Descendants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendantnodes(v=vs.110).aspx) method to achieve what you want:

```
root.Descendants("GrandChild1").Remove();
```